# The Rate of Change in the angle

Tags: calculus, related-rates

> a train 20ft wide is approaching an observer standing in the middle of the track at 100ft/sec.Find the rate of increase of the angle subtended by the train when the train is 20ft from the observer

I'm questioning my intuition on the problem,the way i approached this problem was through the use of $\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ as it allowed me to relate the height of the triangle(the distance to the observer) and the width of the train(half of it) however i'm still in doubt about my approach and the result.

Comment: Your intuition is right. You get a relation between the angle and the distance and then you use the chain rule to relate the rates of change.

Comment: i think what stumped me was that i couldn't understand the word "subtended" since english is not the language i was taught math in. this made drawing the picture quite difficult and for the most part it still is

Comment: "subtended" means the angle you call $\theta$. It is the angle under which the observer sees the train. BTW I was not taught Math in English either..

Comment: Yeah that's what i assumed it meant since it seemed the most logical thing to be measuring glad i was correct,